# $C$-embedded and $C^*$-embedded

Tags: general-topology, functions

The set $C(X)$ of all continuous, real-value functions on a topological space $X$ will be provided with an algebraic structure and order structure and the set $C^{*}(X)$ of $C(X)$, consisting of all bounded function in $C(X)$.

A subspace $S$ of $X$ is $C$-embedded in $X$ if every function in $C(S)$ can be extended to a function in $C(X)$. A subspace $S$ of $X$ is $C^{*}$-embedded in $X$ if every function in $C^{*}(S)$ can be extended to a function in $C^{*}(X)$.

> My questions are:

1:  Does every uniformly continuous function on $\mathbb{R} - \{ 0 \}$ have continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$?

2:Is $\mathbb{N}$, $C $-embedded  or $C^{*}$-embedded in $\mathbb{R} $?

**According to this theorem that $C^{*}$-embedded is $C$-embedded if only if it is completely separated from every zero-set disjoint from it.**

3: Can you give me an example that a $C^{*}$-embedded subspace need not be $C$-embedded?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Uniform continuity implies that $\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}f(x)$ exists, and can be extended naturally to $\mathbb{R}$.

(2) Given a bump function $\rho$ supported on $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ such that $\rho(0)=1$ and $\rho(x)=0$ if $\vert x\vert>\frac{1}{2}$, you can define a function:

$g(x):= \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\cdot \rho(x+n)$ where $f\in C^*(\mathbb{N})$.

Then $g$ extends $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, and $\vert g(x)\vert \leq \underset{n\in \mathbb{N}}{\max} \vert f(n)\vert$, and is also smooth.

Comment: Your example fails as your $f$ is itself unbounded on the natural numbers.

Comment: As to (1) $\infty$ should be $0$ in the limit.

Comment: You're right, I'll change (1) and change(2).

Comment: The (3) argument is nonsense. Think again.  Examples exist but are non obvious

Comment: Can you give me more guidance about 2?

Comment: In (2) I gave a blueprint of a construction for a continuous extension. The arguments there are just somewhat lacking, so is there something you need explaining?